# Did John Wayne create his 5 rules for life?

Tags: united-states, quotes

Did the actor John Wayne create these rules?  They're widely attributed to him, but I couldn't find when and where he said them.

They seem to be widely attributed to him

[Here](https://cowboypress.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/john-wayne-five-rules-to-remember-in-life/)

[Also here](https://kathys-second-half.blogspot.com/2019/05/john-waynes-five-rules-to-remember-in.html)

[image: John Wayne's rules]

Comment: Can you provide an example of where these quotes are attributed to him that isn't just a random image on iFunny?

Comment: 3-5 don't appear to be rules at all...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe John Wayne said it.  But he was probably not the first one.

[Searchquotes](https://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/Money_can%27t_buy_happiness%2C_but_it%27s_a_lot_more_comfortable_to_cry_in_a_Mercedes_than_on_a_bicycle./494140/#ixzz79wdjoy9h) lists the source of

> **Money can't buy happiness, but it's a lot more comfortable to cry in a Mercedes than on a bicycle.**

as "unknown"

Found this [on line](http://uberhumor.com/five-pearls-of-scottish-wisdom):

[image]

See also [The Jewish Humor and Joke Page](http://www.jewishmag.com/96mag/humor/humor.htm)

Comment: You're probably right, but "I found a couple of random websites mentioning it without attributing it to him" feels like rather weak evidence to me. Can you give any reason why these are more likely to be correct than the random websites in the question which _do_ attribute it to him?